# Hypergeometric distribution with $N,M\to \infty$ and $M/N\to p$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is from Casella and Berger Statistical Inference.

> The hyper-geometric distribution can be approximated by either the binomial or the Poisson distribution. Let $X$ have the hypergeometric distribution $$P(X = x|N,M,K) = \frac{{M\choose x}{N-M\choose K-x}}{{N\choose K}}, \ \ x=0,1,\ldots,K$$
>   a.) Show that as $N\to \infty,M\to \infty$, and $M/N\to p$,
>   $$P(X = x|N,M,K)\to {K\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{K-x}, \ \ x=0,1,\ldots,K$$

Partial solution - Let $\ t = M/N\to p, N\to \infty,M\to \infty$ I am going to skip some steps a bit but essentially I get to here:

$${K\choose x}\lim_{t}\frac{M!(N-M)!(N-K)!}{(M-x)!(N-M-(K-x))!N!}$$

This is where I am hinted to use Stirling's formula but I am not really sure how to apply it any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not require Stirling's formula.

Comment: That is great news, can you tell me what I should do then or what I should refer to?

Comment: If you write $\binom Mx = \frac{M(M-1)\cdots (M-x+1)}{x!}$ and similarly for other binomial coefficients, and factor out $x!$, $(K-x)!$, $K!$, these contribute to $\binom Kx$. The remaining fraction after the limit is $p^x(1-p)^{K-x}$.

Comment: thanks ill give that a try, if you want to post a solution I can accept it if not I will wait a little longer and probably delete it then seems from your comment this is not that bad

Comment: @i707107 I don't see how your technique changes anything, could you provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{{M\choose x}{N-M\choose K-x}}{{N\choose K}}\\
&=\frac{K!}{x!(K-x)!} \frac{ M(M-1)\cdots (M-r+1)\cdot (N-M)(N-M-1)\cdots (N-M-(K-x)+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-K+1)}\\
&=\binom Kx \frac{ M(M-1)\cdots (M-r+1)\cdot (N-M)(N-M-1)\cdots (N-M-(K-x)+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-r+1) (N-r)(N-r-1)\cdots (N-K+1)}.
\end{align}
$$
As $M,N\rightarrow \infty$ with $M/N \rightarrow p$, we have for the fraction
$$
\frac{ M(M-1)\cdots (M-r+1)\cdot (N-M)(N-M-1)\cdots (N-M-(K-x)+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-r+1) (N-r)(N-r-1)\cdots (N-K+1)}, separately, 
$$

$$
\frac{M(M-1)\cdots(M-r+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-r+1)} \rightarrow p^r,$$
and
$$
\frac{(N-M)(N-M-1)\cdots (N-M-(K-x)+1) }{(N-r)(N-r-1)\cdots (N-K+1)}\rightarrow (1-p)^{K-r}
$$